# Add number 20 to folder names and (-) between sections

Tags: bash, rename, move

He guys I have folders listed as
230101 230102 230103 - infinite daily made
I need a way in bash or batch to re name the folders to 2023-01-01 as example
But I need it to be automated
So the issue is we need to add number 20 In beginning of the folder name and two - to every folder
Any suggestions?

I have tried to make the name of the files as variable I kept getting a lot of errors so I need someone to guide me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the loop that creates `new_dir` names from sub-strings of `dir` names. The `??????/` glob is used to match only directories with 6-character names:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ??????/; do
  dir=${dir%/}
  new_dir="20${dir:0:2}-${dir:2:2}-${dir:4:2}"
  if [ -d "$new_dir" ]; then
    mv -n "${dir}"/* "$new_dir"/
    rmdir "${dir}"
  else
    mv "$dir" "$new_dir"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i added it to my answer

Comment: #!/bin/bash

for dir in ??????/ do dir=${dir%/} new_dir="20${dir:0:2}-${dir:2:2}-${dir:4:2}" mv "$dir" "$new_dir" done

Is ok but we have another issue to come by if another file was created let's say 230104 it will be moved to the new directory which is already available 2023-01-04 mv "$dir" "$new_dir" No idea how to solve this issue

Comment: What do you want to do with it then? Overwrite it? You can check if the directory already exists and use `rm -rf` to remove it if  so.

Comment: Since the folders are updated daily, let's take 230104 for example again, so we add 20 and the two - right? To make it 2023-01-04 .. after let's say an hour or two another 230104 will appear, but since new_dir is already available, mv "$dir" "$new_dir" will move it inside, which is the issue 2023-01-04/230104

Comment: Yes, i know what is your issue. I asked how do you want to solve it? For example:  A) remove old folder and replace it with new folder. B) merge the contents of old folder with new one? C) Ignore the new folder and keep only old folder? etc ... Please make it clear and i'll try to help

Comment: Thanks alot your code really solved my issue, I need A and B which is merge the contents of old folder also delete 230104

Comment: I added the condition to the answer: if the dir already exists, it should move all contents to the existing one and delete the empty dir afterwards. if the dir doesn't exists, it should rename it.

Comment: More than enough, thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252116/discussion-between-amro-almughrabi-and-protob).

Comment: More than enough, thank you very much.

Dear protob, I know I asked too many questions, I don't know how to thank you really I'm currently facing another issue I want to come by remember the example folders which are like 230104, etc .. they are in multiple directions just like 11111/230104 22222/230105 I can pass by this issue if I duplicate the code and cd the directory everytime, but do you have a another way?